# ESP8266 GET method error

Tags: esp8266

I am working on ESP8266 and I want to send a GET request with AT command to my localhost but I failed every time. Can you help me solve this problem please? Thank you for interest!
I attached my terminal code and my code:

```cpp
#define ag_ismi "SUPERONLINE_WiFi_8022"
#define ag_sifresi "rC5YGNYebuCf"
#define IP "192.168.1.9"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("AT");
  delay(3000);
  if(Serial.find("OK")){
    Serial.println("AT+CWMODE=1"); 
    delay(2000);
    String baglantiKomutu=String("AT+CWJAP=\"")+ag_ismi+"\",\""+ag_sifresi+"\"";
    Serial.println(baglantiKomutu);
    delay(5000);     
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(60000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.9\",8000");
  delay(1000);
  String model = "GET /kanbanDB/arduino?model=1 HTTP/1.1";
  //model+="Host: 192.168.1.9:8000\r\n\r\n";
  model+="r\n\r\n";
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSEND=" + String(model.length()));
  Serial.println("\r\n\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(model);
  Serial.println("\r\n\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(""); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: problem is, that you connected the esp8266 to Serial. now your Serial debug prints go to esp8266 and disturb it. use SoftwareSerial

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
String model = "GET /kanbanDB/arduino?model=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n";
model+="Host: 192.168.1.9\r\n\r\n";
```

remove `Serial.println("\r\n\r\n");` before `Serial.println(model);` it is send before GET line

```
Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.9\",8000");
String model = "GET /kanbanDB/arduino?model=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n";
model+= "Host: 192.168.1.9\r\n\r\n";
Serial.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
Serial.println(model.length());
delay(1000);
Serial.print(model);
delay(1000);
```

EDIT:
Remove debug prints to Serial or use SoftwareSerial to connect the esp8266 to Uno. Now the debug prints are sent to esp8266 mixed with AT commands and data. For SoftwareSerial [change the default baud rate of the AT firmware](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57496/arduino-uno-with-esp8266-01-with-at/57507#57507).

Comment: I tried this code but its also not working. when I run GET /kanbanDB/arduino?model=1 HTTP/1.1 code, if I send first time wifi module waiting 30 second and send requets but second time I run this code it failed. that failure is about power supply ?

Comment: how do you power it?

Comment: I used arduino with USB power