# Not Able to communicate with ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I just bought an Esp8266(not the node MCU) and tried connecting it with Arduino without a USB to serial converter but in vain. I am a beginner and don't know what to do. It is not responding to AT commands. Can anyone give me a detailed step by step process to connect it?[image]

I am using Arduino UNO R3.

This is my connection diagram:-

[image]

I uploaded an empty code(Bare minimum example code), just to see if the AT commands are working, but it failed to respond. I reflashed it, then also it is not working.
when I type AT it shows nothing. But if I shake it, sometimes it shows gibberish.

Comment: Right now all I'm trying to go is get you to bring it up to the state of being an answerable question.  Already looks better than what you started with. Still a ways to go.  I'm confused as to what the thinking behind "uploaded an empty code" is.  How were you thinking that would help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino Uno with ESP8266-01 with AT](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57496/arduino-uno-with-esp8266-01-with-at)

Comment: Hey @Juraj I tried to send some commands, it shows gibberish and wdt reset with rst_cause:4

Comment: If it shows gibberish when you shake it, you have a bad connection somewhere. Also, what code are you trying this with? Do the baud rates match and did you set them to a low enough value (9600 recommended)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Just bought another one and it worked properly.